# User Input Data does not remain after viewing other ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

The user input is typed into the TextFields and TextViews on ViewController1, but when I select a button to show either ViewController2 or ViewController3 via a segue, on my return to ViewController1 (also via another segue), the input is no longer there, as if the app was just reopened.
How do I make the initial user input remain in the text fields and text views while the user switches to a different view and also until the user hits the "Send Email" button back on ViewController1?

Below is my code

**ViewController1**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var DateTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var FirstTextView: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var FirstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var OtherDetailsField: UITextView!

    lazy var datePicker: UIDatePicker = {
        let picker = UIDatePicker()
        picker.datePickerMode = .date
        picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return picker
    }()
    lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        return formatter
    }()

    // Adjust Scroll for Keyboard ------------------
    @objc func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification) {
        guard let keyboardValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
        let keyboardScreenEndFrame = keyboardValue.cgRectValue
        let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)
        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
            ScrollView.contentInset = .zero
        } else {
            ScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, right: 0)
        }
        ScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = ScrollView.contentInset
      //  let selectedRange = OtherDetailsField.selectedRange
      //  OtherDetailsField.scrollRangeToVisible(selectedRange)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Adjust Scroll for Keyboard ---------------
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)

        // Date Picker ---------------
        DateTextField.inputView = datePicker}
    @objc func datePickerChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker){
        DateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){view.endEditing(true)
    }

    // Dismiss Keyboard ------------------
    func setupKeyboardDismissRecognizer(){
        let tapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}

// Add Done Button to keypad toolbar -----------------
extension UITextField{

    @IBInspectable var doneAccessory: Bool{
        get{
            return self.doneAccessory
        }
        set (hasDone) {
            if hasDone{
                addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
            }
        }
    }

    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard() {
        let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        doneToolbar.barStyle = .default

        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonAction))

        let items = [flexSpace, done]
        doneToolbar.items = items
        doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

        self.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
    }

    @objc func doneButtonAction()
    {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
extension UITextView{

    @IBInspectable var doneAccessory: Bool{
        get{
            return self.doneAccessory
        }
        set (hasDone) {
            if hasDone{
                addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
            }
        }
    }

    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard() {
        let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        doneToolbar.barStyle = .default

        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonAction))

        let items = [flexSpace, done]
        doneToolbar.items = items
        doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

        self.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
    }

    @objc func doneButtonAction() {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

**ViewController2**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!

    // Adjust Scroll for Keyboard ------------------
    @objc func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification) {
        guard let keyboardValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
        let keyboardScreenEndFrame = keyboardValue.cgRectValue
        let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)

        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
            ScrollView.contentInset = .zero
        } else {
            ScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, right: 0)
        }
        ScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = ScrollView.contentInset
        //let selectedRange = yourTextView.selectedRange
        //yourTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(selectedRange)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Adjust Scroll for Keyboard ---------------
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }

        // Dismiss Keyboard ------------------
        func setupKeyboardDismissRecognizer(){
            let tapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
                target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))
            tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        }
        func dismissKeyboard()
        {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
```

**ViewController3**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include "what you have tried" ... usually some code.  I have a feeling the problem lies in the fact you are using an additional segue to add an additional (new) VC1 to the viewcontroller stack instead of "popping"/dismissing VC2.

Comment: There should not be any issue with the segue. It might be an issue like creating a new object. Please share the code snippet.

Comment: Hi Boober and Animesh, i just added my code to the question

Comment: the segue to back to viewController1. is it an unwind segue? or are you pushing a new viewController1?

Comment: Both buttons to move between the view are just basic buttons with a "show" segue associated. As for the "send email" button, that is not yet coded, I haven't learnt the code for that button yet.

Answer (score 1):

short answer: **backwards segues that You used create new instances, You could use 'dismiss' method instead or use Tab bar controller.**

long answer:

Firstly, I assume You created Single View Controller when creating project in Xcode, and all segues You used are of "show" type.

Lets say You create segue 'ViewController1->ViewController2' and button 'NEXT' to execute it.

When You click on 'NEXT' You create a new instance of ViewController2, something kinda "new copy".

Next You create another segue to go back:
 'ViewController2->ViewController1' and button 'BACK' to execute.

when You click on 'BACK' button (which triggers segue), You're NOT going back to the original ViewController1, but You're creating a new instance of ViewController1.

So as You can see, using segues this way can create future memory problems when users could go back and forth, every time creating new instance, stacking windows on top of each other.

The easiest solution is to delete segues that point backwards and instead put 'dismiss' method inside your 'BACK' button codeblock:

```
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Every time You use 'dismiss' method, You close the actual ViewController and go back to the previous one.

 If You want something like 'HOME' button to go from any ViewController back to the first one (root), You can use this code:

```
    self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true,completion: nil)
```

But remember - If You don't write some code to save Your data before dismissing, You will still lose the ViewController2 and ViewController3 data when You dismiss them.

Finally, if You need to keep Your data displayed when user switches between ViewControllers, I would use **Tab bar controller**. You can create it using template 'Tabbed App' when You create Xcode project.

Hope this helps! And don't take it as 100%, I'm still a Swift Rookie :)